# Tableau: How to add parameters in Initial SQL

Tags: teradata, tableau-api

I've been stuck with the below and been searching for an answer. Also opened a ticket with Tableau support team and waiting for them to get back.

My Question:

I have some volatile tables that I created in Teradata.

In Tableau with the Live connection I placed the volatile tables in Initial SQL and in my custom SQL i'm just doing a Select * from that Volatile table which works completely fine.

Now, I have to declare a parameter in the initial SQL (This is where a user enters some value on the dashboard in the parameter field and gets the data).

Can this be accomplished? Appreciate your responses.

Comment: Have you considered setting-up a parameter in custom SQL rather than in initial SQL?